# When do you need a dollar symbol before an arithmetic statement in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to get my head around bash but am struggling with some core foundations.

I can see an arithmetic statement is defined by double parentheses

```
((5-3))
```

but if I try to `echo` that or us it in `shift` I get an error

```
echo ((5-3))
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

In examples it shows that prefixing it with a dollar symbol will make it work

```
echo $((5-3))
```

Why is that? The syntax looks as though I'm applying the arithmetic to a blank variable and then onto the `echo` function. Why can't I just pass the result of the arithmetic into the `echo` function? How do I know when to prefix an arithmetic statement with a dollar symbol in other instances.

Please excuse my ignorance. Im so used to web development languages and Bash is just so different.

Comment: Yes BASH is indeed different from web development languages. `$(...)` is called *command substitution*. Do read some BASH scripting tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`((...))` is an arithmetic **expression**.

`$((...))` is an arithmetic **expansion**.

The difference is that an expression is a unit on its own but an expansion just gets replaced with a value.

This is the same thing as the difference between.

```
$ echo foo
foo
```

and

```
$ $(echo foo)
-bash: foo: command not found
```

Comment: I'd phrase this differently: `((...))` is effectively a command of its own; `$((...)) is *part of* a command. If you use `$((5-3)) as a command, it'll calculate the result (2), then try to execute *that* as a command (and unless you happen to have a command named "2", that'll get an error).

Answer (score 2):

This is needed when you need not to only compute but also to return it's value

Answer (score 2):

The double braces are used to tell bash that treat the content within the braces is an integer and the '$' symbol is used to display the result or the resulting integer from the arithmatic